# Prevent AsyncPostBackTrigger if value in the textbox is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have following code in my triggers:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="InitPay" EventName="TextChanged" />
```

while my control looks like:

```
    <label class="ccsp">Initial Payment</label><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="InitPay"  AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnTextChanged="InitPay_TextChanged" Style="width: 300px;">
    </asp:TextBox><b>$</b><br /> 
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="ValInitPay" ControlToValidate="InitPay" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="Val_InitPay" OnServerValidate="ValInitPay_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="Out of range error." Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Jquery validate function:

```
function Val_InitPay(source, args) {
        if (Math.floor($('#InitPay').val()) == ($('#InitPay').val()) && $.isNumeric($('#InitPay').val())) {
            if ($('#InitPay').val() > ($("#InitPaymnet").val()) && $('#InitPay').val() < 1000)
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
            else {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

while the code behind validate function is:

```
protected void ValInitPay_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
            if (int.TryParse(InitPay.Text, out val))
            {
                if (val > 10 && val < 1000)
                {
                    args.IsValid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    args.IsValid = false;
                    ValInitPay.ErrorMessage = "<img  src='images/err_msg.png' height='11px' width='11px' style='vertial-align:middle' />Out of range";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
                ValInitPay.ErrorMessage = "<img  src='images/err_msg.png' height='11px' width='11px' style='vertial-align:middle' />Not an integer";
            }

    }
```

Now when I give an invalid input in the textbox, it rapidly fires the trigger function. It gives the error but then it fires the trigger. Is there a way by which we can stop the trigger when the value is invalid?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If only you use [e.preventdefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) function of jQuery in all code paths where we are assure that the input is not valid than we can stop the server trip. The code will look like this

```
function Val_InitPay(source, args) {
    if (Math.floor($('#InitPay').val()) == ($('#InitPay').val()) && $.isNumeric($('#InitPay').val())) {
        if ($('#InitPay').val() > ($("#InitPaymnet").val()) && $('#InitPay').val() < 1000)
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else {
            args.IsValid = false;
            e.preventdefault()
        }
    }
    else {
        args.IsValid = false;
        e.preventdefault()
    }
}
```